# Что не так со вторым циклом for

Tags: python

Я хочу чтобы чётные и не чётные буквы поменялись местами

```
proverb ='Программисты - это устройства, преобразующие кофеин в код.'
new_proverb=[]
for i in proverb[1::2]:
    new_proverb+=i
    for a in proverb[::2]:
        new_proverb+=a

new_proverb="".join(new_proverb)
print(new_proverb)
```

```
>>>  
рПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдгПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдаПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдмПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдсПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдыПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкд-Пормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдэПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдоПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдуПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдтПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдоПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдсПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдвПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкд,Пормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдпПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдеПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдбПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдаПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдуПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдщПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдеПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдкПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдфПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдиПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкд Пормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкд Пормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкдоПормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкд.Пормит  т срйта рорзюи оенвкд
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно "сшить" вместе два среза с помощью функции `zip`, а потом вывести их, склеив буквы вместе

```
# тестирование на строке с нечётным кол-вом символов
>>> s = 'Программисты - это устройства, преобразующие кофеин в коды.'
>>> z = zip(list(s[1::2]) + [''], s[::2])
>>> ''.join(''.join(letter for letter in pare) for pare in z)
'рПгоарммсиыт- э оту тсорсйвт,ап ербоарузщюеик фоие н вокыд.'

# тестирование на строке с чётным кол-вом символов
>>> s = 'Программисты - это устройства, преобразующие кофеин в код.'
>>> z = zip(list(s[1::2]) + [''], s[::2])
>>> ''.join(''.join(letter for letter in pare) for pare in z)
'рПгоарммсиыт- э оту тсорсйвт,ап ербоарузщюеик фоие н вок.д'
```

---

Объяснение `list(s[1::2]) + ['']`:

1. Если в строке чётное кол-во символов, то в `list(s[1::2]) + ['']`
   будет ровно на один элемент больше, чем в `list(s[::2])`, и функция
   `zip` выбросит лишний элемент (ту самую пустую строку)
2. Если в строке нечётное кол-во символов, то в `list(s[1::2]) + ['']`
   будет столько же элементов, сколько и в `list(s[::2])`, но последний
   элемент первого списка будет пустой строкой. Пустая строка ставится
   в соответствие последнему символу нечётной строки и никак не влияет
   на результат склейки (`'' + 'a' == 'a'`)

Таким образом мы компенсируем возможно существующий нечётный символ в конце, искусственно ставя ему в соответствие пустую строку, чтобы `zip` не выбросила этот последний символ.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас вы после каждого символа с чётной позиции записываете все символы с нечётных позиций, поскольку второй цикл из-за отступов оказывается вложен в первый. Если просто хотите поменять их местами, то логика должна быть примерно такая:

```
is_even = len(proverb) % 2 == 0
# поскольку шагаем по парам, может остаться лишний символ в конце
N = len(proverb) if is_even else len(proverb) - 1
for i in range(0, N, 2):
    new_proverb += proverb[i + 1] + proverb[i]
# добавляем последний символ, если нужно
if not is_even:
    new_proverb += proverb[-1]
```

Если же хотите менять местами только буквы, то уже нужен более хитрый алоритм

Answer (score 0):

```
proverb2 = {}
for i in range(len(proverb)):
     proverb2[i-1 if i%2 else i+1]=proverb[i]

''.join([proverb2[key] for key in sorted(proverb2)])
```

Comment: Добавьте в строку один символ, чтобы их количество стало нечётным, и получите `String index out of range` :)

Comment: Да, согласен, переписал полностью )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, должно сработать:

```
proverb = 'Программисты - это устройства, преобразующие кофеин в код.'
new_proverb = ''
for i in range(0, len(proverb)-1, 2):
    new_proverb += proverb[i +1] + proverb[i]
print(new_proverb)
```